# Do all Users in SSRS need to be a System User in Site Settings?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I need to set up a new SSRS site but I'm not sure if adding Users in the Site Settings as System User is required. I've added the Users to Roles on each folder and the Home folder. Is that enough?

The last few SSRS sites I've used only had BuiltIn\Administrators listed on the Site Settings Security page and Users were given Content Manager roles on the Home folder and sub-folders inherited that. And that worked.

But, most of the guides I see online start by telling you to add each User as a System User in the Site Settings and THEN to add them into Roles in the Home folder. So, I'm confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not required to add all users/groups to the System User role. However, if you do not add users/groups to that role, they will not be able to view shared schedules. In other words, if the users set up subscriptions, they will not be able to pick an existing shared schedule; they will only be able to create a report-specific schedule.

Here is a link to the Microsoft Docs article on that role (link is for SQL Server 2017):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/role-definitions-predefined-roles?view=sql-server-2017#bkmk_systemuser